# Setting up eigen math library with visual studio

Tags: c++, eigen

I have downloaded eigen and am trying to set it up with visual studio. My current file structure looks like this:

`project`:

```
src
Vendor
```

`src`:

`main.cpp`

`Vendor`:

`Eigen`

Here is my main.cpp file.

```
#include "../Vendor/Eigen/Core/Matrix.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Vector3f v;
}
```

I am getting hundreds of errors.
The first error is `identifier uintptr_t is undefined` in file `atomic`.

Edit: I opened the file `"../Vendor/Eigen/Core/Matrix.h"` and it seems to contain errors (some lines have squiggly red underlines).

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Which Visual Studio version?

Comment: From where did you get your Eigen version? The directory structure seems wrong

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I got it from here https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: Check the first error. Is Matrix.h found ?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at `vcpkg` as a way of managing external C++ dependencies in VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only a guess depending on your source structure but you copied the wrong sources:

You need to copy the `Eigen` directory into your `Vendor` not the `src` which is in `Eigen` directory. And then try to:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
```

The structure of Eigen

```
Eigen
|--> .gitlab
|--> Eigen / you need to copy this full directory
     |--> src      / I guess you copied this
     |--> Cholesky
     |--> ...
     ...
|--> bench
|--> ...
...
```